# Syntax error in sql caused by NULL data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

i have field data that consist of NULL. I try to get SUM data by making NULL data as 0.00.

I use

> select Sum(cast(ISNULL (amount,0) as money)) from t

here the [demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b33e7/2)

How to avoid this error
"Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax"

Comment: why on earth would anyone store currency as a string? Everytime you do, a puppy dies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `NULL` is not a null value, but rather a string with the word 'NULL' in it:

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/26694/1/0)

When you change it to a real `NULL` as per the demo, this will work without an `ISNULL()` since aggregates ignore `NULL` values:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(amount as MONEY)) 
FROM t
```

If you need to work around that string value, use `REPLACE()` instead of `ISNULL()`:

```
SELECT SUM(CAST(REPLACE(amount,'NULL',0) as MONEY)) 
FROM t
```

Best practice would of course be to not store numeric as strings, but sadly we cannot always control the data we get.

Comment: "but sadly we cannot always control the data we get" - no, but when you have it you can.

Answer (score 2):

In your demo, you don't actually have a null value in the last record, you have a character string called 'NULL'.  Change it to an actual null value and it should work